# Zend Framework 2 only show required custom validation error message

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a required ISBN field that I would like to change the generic error messages for. I have set up the custom error messages and they work. The filters are part of the `getInputFilterSpecification()` function of the models `fieldSet` which validates and shows the custom error messages correctly:

```
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Validator;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as ClassMethodsHydrator;

class BookItemFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public $Types;

    public function __construct($itemName, $Types)
    {

        parent::__construct($itemName, $Types);

        $this->Types = $Types;

        // .. Other fields

        $bookISBN = new Element\Number('bookISBN');
        $bookISBN->setLabel('Book ISBN ')
            ->setAttribute('id', 'bookISBN');

        // .. more fields

        $this->add($bookISBN);
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(

            'bookISBN' => array(
                'required' => true,
              'validators' => array(
                  new Validator\NotEmpty(array(
                          'setMessage'=> 'ISBN is Required'
                      )
                  ),
                  new Validator\Isbn(array(
                      'setMessage'=> 'ISBN is Invalid'
                  )),

              )
            ),
           //... more input filters

        );

    }
}
```

But when the field is left blank. Both "ISBN is Invalid" and "ISBN is required" messages appear.

Is there a way to only show the required error message if the field is left blank?

something like the following:

```
    'bookISBN' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'setMessage' => 'ISBN is required' // Only this shows if field is empty
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            new Validator\Isbn(array(
                'setMessage'=> 'ISBN is Invalid' // only this shows if the input is invalid
            )),

        )
    ),
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the complete code. I believe the above code is not part of a inputFilter function.

Comment: @KamalSoni, I have added more code, the `inputFilter` is part of the entity's `FieldSet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break the chain by setting it to true, which by default is set to false by Zend. Can you please try and see if below code works.

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(

            'bookISBN' => array(
                'required' => true,
              'validators' => array(
                  array(
                     'name' => 'not_empty',
                     'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                     'options' => array(
                         'messages' => array(
                              \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'ISBN is required',
                         ),
                     ),
                  ),
                  new Validator\Isbn(array(
                      'setMessage'=> 'ISBN is Invalid'
                  )),

              )
            ),
           //... more input filters

        );

    }
```

or may be it is 'NotEmpty'. I can't test it out.

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(

            'bookISBN' => array(
                'required' => true,
              'validators' => array(
                  array(
                     'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                     'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                  ),
                  new Validator\Isbn(array(
                      'setMessage'=> 'ISBN is Invalid'
                  )),

              )
            ),
           //... more input filters

        );

    }
```

Comment: Yes! that worked (both). it now only shows the default `Value is required and can't be empty` message. Could you update the example with the custom error message?